# How to replace values present in particular column with openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I want to replace dates present in a particular format with the standard format of `dd-mm-yyyy`. Actual date present in the 10th column would be like `6.2017`, `7.2017` where `7` is the month and `2017` is the year. I just need to add `1-` before all the values and then I want to replace the dot present in the date value with `-` (hyphen). So the output looks like `1-6-2017`, `1-7-2017`. Note that the column may contain `none` values. In that case, I want to skip those none values.

This is what I tried,

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(r'E:\foo\Python\stocktable.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_active_sheet()
for rownum in range(2, ws.get_highest_row()):
    print(str(ws.cell(row=rownum, column=10).value))
```

**Output:**

```
6.2017
7.2016
7.2017
6.2017
7.2017
7.2017
2.2016
7.2017
8.2016
None
```

So I add a litle bit tweak to the above code, to work for my case. But it fails.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(r'E:\foo\Python\stocktable.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_active_sheet()
for rownum in range(2, ws.get_highest_row()):
    ws.cell(row=rownum, column=10).value = '1-' + str(ws.cell(row=rownum, column=10).value.replace('.', '-')

wb.save(r'E:\foo\Python\stocktable.xlsx')
```

That is, it shows a symtax error like,

```
File "E:\foo\Python\python-excel.py", line 7
    wb.save() 
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails"? what is the error? How about putting `month, year = ws.cell(row=rownum, column=10).value.split(".")` followed by  `ws.cell(row=rownum, column=10).value = year  + "-" + month + "-" + "01"`?

Comment: Why do you need to give the name of the file again when saving? Try using `wb.save()` instead.

Comment: @shahkalpesh I tried, but it fails. `TypeError: save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the formatting of dates or times, you only need to change the `number_format` for the cells.

```
for row in range(2, ws.max_row):
   cell = ws.cell(row=row, column=10)
   cell.number_format = "dd-mm-yyyy"
```

Comment: Excel treats dates as floats, using only formatting to differentiate them.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I figured out the problem and the below code works for me.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(r'E:\foo\Python\stocktable.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_active_sheet()
for rownum in range(2, ws.get_highest_row()):
    try:
        month, year = str(ws.cell(row=rownum, column=10).value).split(".")
        ws.cell(row=rownum, column=10).value = '1-' + str(month) + '-' + str(year) 
    except ValueError:
        pass    

wb.save(r'E:\foo\Python\stocktable.xlsx')
```

Like @shahkalpesh said in his comment, I just split the string (At first it was in float format, so I convert it to string and then do splitting based on dot) according to the dot and save the values to `month` and `year` variable.

Then I put the code inside `try` `except` block since the column contains `none` values.

Comment: May i know the reason for downvote? I think this would be helpful for future readers.

Comment: Your code displays a complete lack of understanding of data formats. Going via strings to convert between numbers and dates is definitely the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @CharlieClark I want to convert it to a string like the above since the input is in decimal format. Later the navicat software automatically converts the that string format to date.

Comment: Much easier to take the integer and real parts from the number and create a date object. openpyxl will format this automatically. You're depending upon heuristics (guess work) otherwise.

Comment: It's also better to check explicitly whether the cell has a value or not, if this is what you want, rather than using try: except. The ValueError could be raised by other functions.

Comment: you mean this `if not ws.cell(row=rownum, column=10).value is None:` ?  I think it's a good idea.